# how to validate a grid cell properly

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, gridview

I am trying to validate a user input on a grid cell. I can validate the input but I need to focus back on the same cell because the user should enter a valid value again.But the focus goes to the cell below if the user hits enter,if tab is hit, it goes to the cell next to it. You can see my almost done function below,

```
private void gv_ValidateRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ValidateRowEventArgs e)
{
   decimal amount = (decimal)gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["AMOUNT"]);
   decimal max_kg = (decimal)gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["MAX_KG"]);

   if (amount > max_kg) {
      gv.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["AMOUNT"], 0);
      XtraMessageBox.Show("Girilen miktar MAX.KG'dan büyük olamaz.");
      gv.FocusedRowHandle = e.RowHandle;
   }
}
```

How can I make it focus back on the same cell to re-enter amount?

Should I use a different event to validate?

Comment: Set `e.Valid = false` to prevent the validation to finish and let the user move to the next row/column.

Comment: I tried e.Valid but it doesnt do that either. It only popups up a "MessageBox.YesNo" which says "would you like to enter a valid value?". If you click NO, then it focuses on the next cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DevExpress documentation on Validating Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument749), you should be setting `e.Validate = false` in the [ValidateRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ValidateRowtopic) event and handle the [`InvalidRowException`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_InvalidRowExceptiontopic) event

Handling the `InvalidRowException` event will prevent the Error message box coming up, which gives the user an option of "Yes" or "No".

```
private void gv_InvalidRowException(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.InvalidRowExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  //Suppress displaying the error message box
  e.ExceptionMode = ExceptionMode.NoAction;
}
```

Please read the documentations linked for additional information regarding error handling with the DevExpress components (which is off-topic for this answer, but good to know)